# Copiar en cascada en Laravel

Tags: laravel

Buenas tardes,

Pongamos de ejemplo que quisiera copiar en cascada un usuario con todos sus contenidos presentes en otras tablas. Estas tablas enlazadas a usuarios.

Usuario
  - Páginas preferidas
  - Servicios

En laravel, cómo podría copiar ese usuario y sus tablas enlazadas. Es decir, como un copiado en cascada.

Un saludo,

Comment: Cuando dices copiar en cascada a que te refieres. A crear otro usuario pero con los datos del que deseas copiar??

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que cree una restricción de "**clave externa**" para este caso. Además, dado que se trata de una relación muchos a muchos, puede utilizar el método detach () en su modelo Eloquent (si las relaciones se establecieron correctamente en su usuario y en sus modelos).

```
$user = App\User::find(1);
// Detach all roles from the user...
$user->roles()->detach();
```

Puede ver la documentación para [para más detalles](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships).